# Access the content of a pointer declared in a structure

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

i have the following structure

```
  typedef struct 
    {
  char *head;
  char *tail;
  int  Size_Of_Element;
  int  Capacity;    
    }queueHandle;

    queueHandle *queue;
```

and i want to change the value of the memory location that *head points. if it was a simple pointer it would be *head = *content (content is a pointer to an array). I suppose i cannot use the queue -> head = *content, because this is how i change the value of head and not the value that head points to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that like this:

`*(queue->head) = *content`

Comment: The parentheses aren't necessary. `*queue->head = *content` would do.